# Any Concurrency Issues with my code

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io, thread-safety

I a trying to create a thread-safe method.

Does anyone see any concurrency issues with following code?

To me it seems fine , **though I could never find a way to test for concurrency on this method.** Any help would be appreciated.

```
   //static locker for thread synchronization
   private static readonly System.Object _object3 = new System.Object();

   //this method needs to be thread-safe
   public static void LogToTextFile(string logMessage, LogLevel logType)
    {
       //make sure only one thread executes this file writing code at a time            
       lock (_object3)
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"c:\logs\log1.txt");
            {
                w.WriteLine("\r\n{0} logged at {1} {2} : {3}", logType.ToString().ToUpper(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), logMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're fine with the performance hit of strict serialisation, this should work fine. (That's more of a general case comment, you can't really not serialise I/O anyway.) Concurrency issues tend to arise from coordinating access to multiple "resources", or dealing with resources that are shared, which isn't your case.

Comment: Oh, also, obviously a problem could occur if some other code tries to open the same file.

Comment: @millimose - you mean another piece of code writes to same file OR reads from same file. I think reading would not cause problems, but writing would?

Comment: @Sunil: another piece of code that opens the same file, but without consulting the same lock object `_object3`.

Comment: @Sunil I'll admit I don't actually have a clue what happens when two processes attempt to access the same file simultaneously, or when a single process has two handles to it. (For this reason alone I'd avoid this.) Reading should be okay since you only ever append to the file, and it's a logfile anyway, nothing bad happens if a read ends mid-message.

Comment: @rwong- Ok. I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no concurrency problems with this code because you are allowing only a single thread to write to the file due to the lock statement.

Comment: Thanks. My main problem was I could not test it. I guess its very difficult, if not impossible, to simulate concurrent access to a method in VS 2010?

Comment: @Sunil How so? Just create a bunch of threads that call it. The problem comes when simulating the wrong kind of concurrent access, since you have nowhere near the required amount of control over scheduling.

Comment: There's tools that systematically analyze your code. One is [chess](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/)

Comment: To simulate multiple callers is easy. Just do in a loop `var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LogToTextFile(...));` . However, what is difficult (or theoretically futile or useless) is to try proving its correctness through ad-hoc testing (leaving scheduling to chance). These kinds of proofs are usually invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you'e `lock`ing around an appropriately-scoped object, I see no concurrency issues with your code.

However, as millimoose mentioned in the comments, you have a potential performance problem. If two threads try to `LogToTextFile` at the same time, one is going get the lock first, and the other is going to block while the file is opened, written to, and then closed. This may not be acceptable, depending on what your threads are doing.

If what I mention is a problem, you'll have to implement a more complex thread-safe logger. Typically there would be a queue to which log events are quickly written. Then there is another thread who periodically wakes up, and empties the queue to the file on disk. All operations on the queue are done with a lock.

Comment: The problem *could* be worked around by gathering the log messages in a queue then having another one handle IO, but this would only help if log messages come in bursts. And very likely lead to more complicated synchronisation problems.

Comment: Agreed, it's not a trivial task to implement such a reader-writer logger. However, without knowing what his application is actually doing, I can't tell whether the blocking approach will be acceptable or not.

Comment: @Jonathan - Isn't that a trade-off when you want to make a method thread-safe?

Comment: @Sunil Not really. I'd expect concurrent code to favour lock-free queues etc. over locking whenever possible.

Comment: @Jonathan- I meant there could be a performance bottleneck by using thread synchronization according to you, which is a price paid for making my code thread-safe. So trade-offs would always be there.

Comment: @Sunil There are many, many ways to "synchronize threads" (i.e. write correct concurrent programs) besides sharing resources and locking around them. The reader-writer logger I mentioned could be implemented using a queue that allows for nonlocking appends (to maximise throughput of log message senders) but blocking reads (to make implementing the thread handling the IO easier). With luck, such a beast is available in a library already.

Comment: @Sunil Like, say, a [`BlockingQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) which by default wraps the lock-free [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx). Or the ever-popular approach that is "punt synchronisation problems to a relational database and hope transactions take care of everything."

Comment: @millimoose - If I use a BlockingQueue to append log messages to, then I would need to run a thread every 'x' seconds to write queued log messages to a file, by using a System.Threading.Timer. Right?

Comment: @Sunil No. If you use a `BlockingQueue`, that thread can just run in an infinite loop and use `BlockingQueue.Take()`. The queue will, well, block until more entries come in. (Do note that you will also have to take care of shutting this down somehow again.) Also: I would use your original approach until it proves to be a bottleneck. This would only happen if log messages are emitted in concentrated bursts. Since writing them to disk is IO-bound, if they come in evenly, it doesn't matter which threads writes them out really as long as they're not waiting for one another.

Comment: @Sunil And obviously, if you "evenly" get more log messages than you can write out to disk, you've got worse problems already.

Comment: @millimose - Something like this: while (blockingQueue.Count > 0) { LogToTextFile(blockingQueue.Take(), logLevel);}

Answer (score 1):

Another, possibly better solution may be to leave the file opened, and use a synchronized `TextWriter` to perform the writes.  [`TextWriter.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx) provides a thread-safe wrapper around a `TextWriter`:

> All write operations to the returned wrapper will be thread safe. You call this method to ensure that only one thread at a time can execute the methods on the TextWriter instance that is returned.

Here's a simple implementation. Note, this has not been tested.

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    private static TextWriter s_writer;

    // Not thread-safe. Call this before other threads are allowed to call Log.
    public void Open(string filename) {
        s_writer = TextWriter.Synchronized( File.AppendText(filename) );
    }

    // Also not thread-safe.
    public void Close() {
       s_writer.Dispose();
    }

    // Thread-safe.
    public void Log(string logMessage, LogLevel logType) {
        s_writer.WriteLine("\r\n{0} logged at {1} {2} : {3}",
            logType.ToString().ToUpper(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), logMessage);
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Jonatah - The only problem with creating a static TextWriter, is if an unexpected error occurs, then how will we ensure that Close() method is definitely called?

Comment: I suppose another option would be to not use a `Synchronized` TextWriter, but instead `lock` on the TextWriter object, and catch any exceptions, calling `Close()` on the writer. Again, I'm just trying to give the OP some direction, not provide a threadsafe logger implementation for him.

Answer (score 1):

There are no concurrency issues within this specific function.  The `lock` statement will properly moderate access to the inner code.

However there are still potential concurrency issues with accessing `@"c:\logs\log1.txt"`.  It's possible that another part of your application, or another process on the same machine, will try to write to the file at the same time as your code.  Hence it's possible the `StreamWriter` code will fail even with this lock.

There is no way to work around this type of concurrency issues.  The file system is a shared resource that you have no true capability to protect.  Instead your code needs to accept that the file system access can fail and properly handle that consequence.

Typically when dealing with logging functions I wrap file system access with a `try / catch` and swallow any exceptions that occur.  Otherwise you run the risk of a logging function failure taking down an application.  That may or may not be acceptable for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I changed the LogToTextFile method, so it now attempts to write to the file again for a max of 5 attempts, in case of an error. I write to file using a try-catch. I do not throw any exception in catch. Makes my code very professional. Hope I could give you a million points.

Comment: Else my logging library was throwing an exception if I opened the log file in Notepad and saved it, while logging was going on.